# Question put on hold as off-topic

Tags: discussion

I am here from last 3 years and getting great help from this community. But I have not much impact on this community. Always my questions are either down-voted or put on hold or deleted. Some due to valid reasons but not all.

Now this question: [Import media image from XML file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182866/import-media-image-from-xml-file) has been put on hold as off-topic but I don't think it is off topic. [There are other questions related to this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=h%26o+import) and has been well treated. And what I got from [help center](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is:

> Magento Stack Exchange is for users of and developers working with the Magento e-Commerce platform. Questions which involve custom code or extensions should include relevant code and, where applicable, an indication that the custom coder or extension vendor has been contacted for support.

I think, this particular question should not be closed. Please give your views.

Comment: @sv3n Users with 10,000 rep can see deleted posts: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: @7ochem so you would not close this?

Comment: @sv3n no, it would be better if a 10k+ user could update the question with (a summary of) the original content

Comment: @7ochem "should" update ... nobody below 10k can check this now to leave a comment ...

Answer (score 2):

I've flagged this as Off-Topic too, but it seems to be wrong here:

> Questions about third-party modules are generally off-topic **because the scope of functionality and code are not available**

Code is available at GitHub, so everybody can investigate it ... voted to reopen.

Answer (score -1):

I am the first voter to close this question,

First you look at the rule for third party question

["3rd Party" close reason text misleading?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/986/3rd-party-close-reason-text-misleading)

we give some time to third party question if any one willing to answer,

for this question till one day no one is willing to answer, I voted to close this question,

because we have to maintain our site answer ratio for healthy site, if no one willing to answer third party question we will close those question.

even we celebrate day called magestackday where we find third party questions ,

and if there were no answer then we close those questions and make site clean.

so for my opinion don't take it personally, and feel free to ask any question.

Comment: First of all thanks for reply. I am not taking it personally. The question you linked has an answer that states `but, posting a significant part of the extension in the question (the one that causes the problem) should make it on topic.`. What will you say about that?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Yes If you write that peice of code then I will vote for reopen your question

Comment: I have already given in my config section.